# Wicket and Hibernate optimal place for sorting and filtering

Tags: hibernate, sorting, wicket, filtering, dataview

my name is Hen and I'm working on an Apache Wicket Web App that has of course a page with some data as table that is grabbed from a database through hibernate and a DAO using a wicket dataprovider.

This data should be sortable by column and filterable through some drop down menus.

The real question I'm asking myself is, where to apply the filters and search criteria.

I could let hibernate do the lifting every time I click a column or chose a value through the drop down, but the data would always be grabbed freshly from the database.

I imagine it would be more performant to only reload the data in a time interval or if the whole page gets reloaded.

The real question is now, should I only fetch the data "as is" once from the database as the page loads and cache the list and apply the filter and sorting on the resulting list, or should I let do hibernate the lifting everytime a column is clicked or a filter value is chosen?

Some insight here would be appreciated.

In best regards

Hen

P.S.: English isn't my native language I would like to pardon in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do the display logic in `Wicket` and the `DAO` stuff as much in `Hibernate` as possible

I recommend using a `DataTable` and a `SortableDataProvider`.

See this example:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Simple+Sortable+DataTable+Example

Implement the `iterator()` method to use your Hibernate Query and return the items that you need.

You can also use `AjaxDataTable` if you care about only redrawing certain rows if they are changed somehow.

If you worry about hitting the database, you should look into the Hibernate Caching techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Hen.

Solution depends on several items, like how many users are you expected to work with your WebApp, how many results your table would contain and how much memory your JVM has.

When we develop search result list in our first project, we simply loads all results in cache and stored them until user session does not ends. It caused such lags (because of GC working), when memory ended up, that we had to restart our server again and again.

But on the other hand users could sort results as they want. Max result was about 5000 elements and we show them in `PageableListView`. In this project there was not so many users, and we solve this problem by reducing session time and adding memory to server.

In our second project we develop dynamic `PageableListView` that loads items only when particular page is opened.

When `ListView` initilizing we search objects with initial sorting, but fetch ONLY IDS from db and pass them as a Model of `ListView`. Then, when particular page is opened, we load only few items and cache them. Such logic can be obtained by overriding `onBeforeRender()` method of the `PageableListView`, like:

```
 @Override
 protected void onBeforeRender() {
      loadSubList((int) getCurrentPage());
      super.onBeforeRender();
 }
```

So, when `populateItem( ListItem<String> item )` is called we just fetch from cache real object according to `item.getModelObject()` value.

Of course, when we need to resort items there is another db request proceeds, but it is not so large relatively to memory and you can clear your previous cache.

In such approach I didn't see any lags with working with db.

I'm not sure, but I think, that we have do something similar with datatables too.

All in all, it's your choice to cache all items, or fetch them from db, but you must analyze what kind of WebApp you developing and what resources do you have, to make right decision.

Answer (score 0):

the question above is from me. Thank you for the details. I can't vote anymore that I got the needed answer.

It's a combination from Michael Zhavzharov and RobAu.

I use a DataView and do the caching in the DAO. In the DataProvider iterator I give the desired Filters that i can plug in in a decorator approach to filter out the undesired results with the needed values and plug them together with the sort() to retrieve my data from hibernateDAO.

The data will be reloaded from the database on certain events, like a new row is added. but otherwise only loaded initially, other request will be answered from the cached List.

In the case some one is interested in the way i try to solve it...

https://henhan.mensa.uberspace.de/java-filtering-and-sorting/

Many, many thanks from me :-D

Greetings

Hen